# How to train a machine learning classification model when there are more than one correct label?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, classification, data-science, multilabel-classification

I have a simple dataset with 20 features and 8 possible labels. For some of the records, however, there could be more than one correct label. 
I would like to train this model such that the predicted label is one of the possible labels. What would be a good way to accomplish this?

Example: Consider the following record:

```
[color: grey; legs:2; wings:2; mass: 120g;....]
```

Some records are labeled as "Sparrow" and few others are named as "Bird". During testing, I don't care which of these labels are assigned to the record as long as it is one of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This certainly depends on the model, but if you're using a neural network with cross-entropy loss, it is entirely possible. In usual case, the label is a one-hot vector `[0, ..., 0, 1, 0, ... 0]`. It's probabilistic interpretation is that target class is `i` with probability `1.0` (and `0.0` for all other classes).

Nothing stops you from defining the label `[0, ..., 0, 0.5, 0, ..., 0,  0.5, 0, ... 0]`: the correct class is `i` with probability `0.5` and `j` with probability `0.5`. The model thus learns that both of these labels are correct for a given input. After the model is trained, you can even output two or more classes, e.g. all classes which probability is higher than `threshold`. Or you can always pick the max probable class, in this case either class can be selected.

Note that this trick (called *soft classes*) works only with *probabilistic* models, and not all machine learning algorithms are probabilistic. So the choice the model matters here.

Comment: I am, indeed, using neural network with cross entropy loss. Your answer is very helpful. I will try the approach you have recommended.